# Translation for EditForm html field's title attribute

Tags: list-form, localization

Where does SharePoint 2010 get the translations for the title attribute of a html control on the EditForm? E.g.: `'Check if External Item exists'` gets translated to `'Controleren of er externe items zijn'` in dutch, but I can't find both strings in any resource file, or even the whole SharePoint hive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear that you will not like the answer - expecially if you hoped to change that text.

The resource you are searching for is embedded inside the Microsoft.SharePoint.intl dll.
As far as I know, many of the classes in the Microsoft.Sharepoint dll uses resource set programmatically at code level and so do the web controls in the Microsof.Sharepoint.WebControls namespace. If I'm not mistaken, the class use in the localization process should be [SPResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spresource.aspx), which in turn uses a ResourceManager based on the Microsoft.Sharepoint.intl dll. The controls should use one of the available static GetString(...) method (for example [SPResource.GetString Method (CultureInfo, String, Object()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms468428.aspx), which in turn use a ResourceManager linked to the aforementioned intl.dll.

If you need to, you could confirm this with a tool like Reflector and looking at the resource for the Microsoft.SharePoint.intl dll.

Comment: already thought it was something like that, I'll check it at work tomorrow.